# TFS 2017 Rest API - Supported Parms?

Tags: api, tfs

TFS 2017 Rest API - How can I confirm what parameters my On Prem Install of TFS supports for each API call?

MS has a reference page, but it only lists v 4.1 and 5.1.  For some reason MS decided that any earlier version (2017 is just "TOO OLD" to leave up) lol

Answer (score 2):

You could press F12, and you'll find **api-version** information under `Network`. For example, you want to check the capacities of a iteration in a team, you'll see the `api-version` information in the screenshot:

[image]